# Fast modular exponentiation with factorial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, factorial

I have a task 50!+7^133 mod 5.

I know that 7^133(mod5)=2(mod5) because:

7=2(mod5)

7^2=4(mod5)

7^3=3(mod5)

7^4=1(mod5)

7^133= 7^(4*33+1)=(7^4)^33*7^1=1*2=2(mod5)

I'm not quite sure how can I calculate 50 in factorial. Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! $50!$ is a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \le b$ then
$b! \equiv 0 \bmod a$.

In this problem,
$50! \equiv 0 \bmod 5$.

Comment: Hmm, I can not understand.

Comment: For what number do you refer a and b? Can you please clarify this? Thank you!

Comment: See my addition.

Comment: Now I understood.